# How do I show a few of items (out of many) in my database table?

Tags: c#, database

C# visual studio 2012 professional asp.net

I have a table containing usernames: Josh, Jeremy, Jared, Justin...

And I created a web page gridview that shows the entire table but I only want it to show Justin and nothing else.

How do I do this?

Here's some code that didn't work:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    SqlDataReader rs;

    con.Open();

    SqlParameter uName = new SqlParameter("paramFName", Account.Text);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(uName);

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE FName=@paramFName";
    rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    rs.Close();
```

Am I supposed to create a view of the table? I tried but wasn't successful.

tips?

Comment: _Didn't work_ is not enough information. Any exception or error message?

Comment: What does not work ? Currently your code would show all entry with athe give nFName. What result do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: when i run the website it still shows the entire table not the select rows with my name

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to select the first 10 names for example then you need to change your SQL Select to the following:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Transactions WHERE FName=@paramFName";
```

Is that what you were after?

EDIT

OK so you are not actually displaying your data anywhere which is the actual problem.

You need to create a datatable and display it in a gridview.

Check out the following links for examples:

[Gridview examples](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=172)

[MSDN Gridview examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx)

Comment: my problem is that my code is not being displayed on my website. it still shows all the names

Comment: Can you post a bit of code for where you are actually trying to display it as well then?

Comment: I think that's my problem I don't know how to do that!!!
How do i display things. Am i supposed to create a VIEW or i do it through the grid view options????

Comment: @user2456977 I have updated my answer a bit for you, hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You simply missed the `"@"` at the parameter name:

```
SqlParameter uName = new SqlParameter("@paramFName", Account.Text);
```

In case of your where-clause this has the effect that you didn't provide anything for the specified parameter which simply let the query provider ignore this condition, which results in the effective query `SELECT * FROM Transactions`.

Beside you should think about using the `using` block:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE FName=@paramFName";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramFName", Account.Text);

    con.Open();
    using (var rs = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        //ToDo: Do something with the reader.
    }
}
```

And another hint: If you need to fill up a `DataTable` with the result, you can use a `SqlDataAdapter` instead of using the data reader:

```
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.TableName = "QueryResult";
    adapter.Fill(dataTable);

    return dataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, although you do not provide much information.

If you're using SQL Server 2012 have a look at the keywords [OFFSET and FETCH](http://www.pertell.com/sqlservings/archive/2012/07/offset-fetch-in-sql-server-2012/).
For earlier versions you need to use [ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

As a good practice you should always limit the number of elements returned.

Comment: my problem is that my code is not being displayed on my website. it still shows all the names

Comment: What is the value of "Action.Text"? As @oliver said you're missing a @ in the param name 'paramFName';

Comment: I did that and nothing happened. Action.Text is a label. I give it the value of the username